# Animating ZBrush models with Blender for unity

Tags: animation, import, unity

Hi Guys I'm trying to make my game and I want to use ZBrush to make my character models, but I want to animate them, to use them in unity with unity new addition (Animator) that is amazing, I remembered that Blender can animate models for using them in unity so I wanted to know if I can make the model in zbrush, animate it in blender and use it in unity!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

I would recommend to export a low poly version of your character from zbrush and a normal map of the high poly model. Then you import in blender the low poly mesh, rig it, animate it, etc... Then import in unity the blend file and the high poly normal map that you assign on the character's material.

Comment: Thanks bro thats amazing :D, do you know any tutorial for good learning of all that High Poly, Low Poly, normal map, I'm starting at this of 3D and I don't understand tons of those terms.

Comment: Well you should start by looking in google.

Comment: Jejeje thats okay bro :) Thanks you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that only create highpoly model in Zbrush, Decimate it and export if for blender.

Cause, any low poly mesh, which you create in Zbrush, will be un-usable in blender due to Triangles. Also, it will be a problem to animate the Zbrush Low Poly (which is very high, in terms of polygon, as far as blender/game engine is concerned). So, you need to create your lowpoly model in Blender.

Since you are starting in 3D development, its better to invest your time learning blender for modeling and sculpting, instead of trying to learn 2 different applications.
Blender is also very suitable for game modeling and has better asset pipeline when it comes to exporting for unity.

To learn more about Blender. Visit www.blendercookie.com and for unity www.unitycookie.com